# Cannot use dot before redirect to file in batch file

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, redirection

I cannot tell why the context of an `if` would change my ability to run the same code.

While this:

```
@SET FILE_MAIL_BODY=mail.body
@echo The build FAILED because of a lock on the 'classes' folder (or its subfolders).>%FILE_MAIL_BODY%
```

works just fine, running the following snippet:

```
@SET retval=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %retval% == 1 (
    @SET FILE_MAIL_BODY=mail.body
    @echo The build FAILED because of a lock on the 'classes' folder (or its subfolders).>%FILE_MAIL_BODY%  
)
```

fails with the message:

```
. was unexpected at this time.
```

, unless I delete the `.` after `subfolders`.

Comment: http://www.zeyalabs.ch/posts/2010/echoing-parentheses-in-batch-files/

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308586/using-batch-echo-with-special-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `()` open and closed parenthesis characters in the `ECHO` command with the  `^` caret character (see below) so it'll be: `@echo The build FAILED because of a lock on the 'classes' folder ^(or its subfolders^).>%FILE_MAIL_BODY%`.

```
@SET retval=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %retval% == 1 (
    @SET FILE_MAIL_BODY=mail.body
    @echo The build FAILED because of a lock on the 'classes' folder ^(or its subfolders^)^.>%FILE_MAIL_BODY%  
)
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Some characters characters, have special meaning to the command line. They cannot be printed as text using the ECHO command unless escaped using the caret ^ symbol:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Escaped_characters_in_strings)
- [SO - Batch Character Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping)
- [Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)
- [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- > ### Echoing Parentheses in Windows Batch Files
  >
  > ***It’s not just about parentheses, really. It’s about almost anything
  >   that a script engine will ruthlessly interpret before executing a
  >   command***: variable markers (percent signs), redirection symbols,
  >   parentheses, double quotes, ampersands…
  >
  > My most common… let’s say, case, is this:
  >
  > ```
  > @echo off
  >
  > echo Doing something (very important)...
  > ```
  >
  > Put this in a BATch file, run it, and you’ll end up with a message
  >   saying
  >
  > ```
  > ... was unexpected at this time.
  > ```
  >
  > No, seriously? It’s great that the engine is trying to evaluate an
  >   expression within an echo, but this time I need something much more
  >   simple: round brackets embedded into a text message. Just that.
  >   Please.
  >
  > Thank heavens there is a “cure”: parentheses can be escaped with a
  >   caret character.
  >
  > ```
  > @echo off
  >
  > echo Doing something ^(very important^)...
  > ```
  >
  > Now we’re good:
  >
  > ```
  > Doing something (very important)...
  > ```
  >
  > Carets can be used to escape almost any special character, even a
  >   newline — to break a single command in several lines.
  >
  > <sub>[source](http://www.zeyalabs.ch/posts/2010/echoing-parentheses-in-batch-files/)</sub>

Comment: Already tried to escape the dot, with the same result. (Pasted the line you provided, too - no change.)

Comment: Escaping the parentheses on top of the dot did it! Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain *why* this needs to be done? What is going on here?

Comment: @OhadSchneider I just added some reference and further resources and quoted a few simple explanations from some of those sources. Please see my updated answer when you get a chance as it may further help clarify for readers moving forward with this regard. Thank you for pointing that out to me and asking the question. I noticed that the article I quoted is the one you found too so I think it does help clarify with the regard you are talking about so nice find there too btw. I noticed after I put it on my answer too ...

Comment: @McDonald's great job! (sorry for the late response)